# Linear result until a specific number

Tags: linear-algebra

I need a formula that retuns x=y up to a specific x, then 0.

y(x) = x, if x<=a
y(x) = 0, if x>a

Comment: Typically you would just write it as $y(x)=\begin{cases} x&x\le a\\0&x>a\end{cases}$. If you need anything more than that, you need to explain more precisely what you need. If, for example, your question comes out of *programming* background ("I need a formula because I can't/won't use the `if` statement"), then you must tell us what you *can* use.

Comment: Agreed with @StinkingBishop . You can also write it as $y=x\mathbb{1}_{x\leq a}$

Comment: What you have is a perfectly valid definition of a function, and arguably the most natural one. You could write it as $\,f(x) = \min(x, a)\,$ or $\,f(x) = \frac{x+a - |x-a|}{2}\,$ but that would only obfuscate it unnecessarily.